# How do I match the different USB cable colors from two different USB cables?

Tags: phone

I have two USB cord with the following color wires:

1. Pink, grey, white and green.
2. Red, white, black and green.

How do I match them together?

Comment: Check (with a multi-meter) which pin matches which cable. You can continue from there and connect matching pins.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Its a good idea to just replace failed cables in most cases. While its tempting to try to save money on it, there's much more to this than "solder this end to this end and heatshrink each cable".

Splicing is dangerous if you don't know what you're doing, and typically there's no reason to do it for data connectors (especially where specific connector types are meant for specific applications).

In fact, if you hook up a type A to type A connector, its against the specifications (people do that anyway, but some assume that means you can connect them PC to PC. Don't) . Otherwise, it makes more sense to cut the cables to length and solder on just the appropriate end (for more consistent cable types, lower resistance and better strain resistance.

That said, you don't know if the cable is to specification, even with appropriate ends. For that matter the *[internal resistance](http://goughlui.com/2014/10/01/usb-cable-resistance-why-your-phonetablet-might-be-charging-slow/)* of the cable matters. Some cables also have [pull up resistors](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb2.shtml) for identifications. I'm pretty sure its not a type C cable but if it was, poor design can be *[dangerous](https://superuser.com/questions/1100903/how-do-i-work-out-if-a-usb-c-cable-is-safe-to-use)*

Even if it is, you're basically adding a big blob of solder to a *complex* set of connectors. Are you that certain of your soldering skills (If you want to twist-splice and tape over, that's even worse)?.

USB cables are *cheap*, *phones and pcs aren't*. Especially if you're unsure of which cables do what, whether its supposed to be a crossover cable (which USB never is) and the fact that the tools you need to halfway do things correctly (2 dollar USB cables vs 15 dollar cheap multimeter + soldering iron + wire stripping) cost more than a few new cables.