# Is high voltage damage caused by faulty USB cables limited to Type-C standard?

Tags: usb

Hardware damage caused by USB Type-C cables by drawing too much power has been widely reported:

- https://www.howtogeek.com/240777/watch-out-how-to-buy-a-usb-type-c-cable-that-wont-damage-your-devices/
- http://www.theverge.com/2016/2/4/10916264/usb-c-russian-roulette-power-cords
- http://www.pcworld.com/article/3002064/computers-accessories/beware-bad-usb-c-cables-google-engineer-warnswhile-naming-names.html
- http://gizmodo.com/cheap-usb-c-cables-could-kill-your-phone-or-laptop-1757115350
- http://www.androidcentral.com/usb-c-problem-isnt-going-away-anytime-soon

Can other [USB connector types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Connector_types) cause this type of damage? Is this issue entirely limited to Type-C?

Comment: `Can other USB connector types cause damage`. Yes. You can attempt to force a connector in the wrong way. You could use the edge of the connector to scratch another component/item... You can use it as a whip! However, I guess you should edit your question and explain what you mean to avoid ambiguity

Comment: @User598527 - you might want to clarify what types of damage you are askign about... you can do loads of damage with a USB A if you push it too far into a RJ45 Ethernet Socket (Its how I killed the NIC on my old dell laptop!)

Comment: All of your articles refer to the same thing, and each one describes the cables that are problematic.  What are you asking that is not already answered in the articles you cite?

Comment: Yes, this is an issue with Type-C interconnect. It allows for higher power to be drained from a host if it is capable of it. However, when a fake cable is made that signals to a device that the host end is high-current (but it is a regular host, legacy cables do not know host capability), the device will try to take this power and cause port overcurrent. Badly-designed hosts may be damaged. The problem is in fake, non-compliant legacy cables.

Comment: Full explanation is given here https://superuser.com/a/1104229/620011

Comment: @AliChen: I didn't find that question because of incorrectly spelled title title.

Comment: @fixer1234: The other USB standards.

Answer (score 1):

The problem being reported is that there are cables being constructed using older USB components (i.e. the connector on the end), and these older USB components that can't handle the amount of power the USB-C device may be drawing from the computer using USB-C's "fast charging" standards.

Using under-rated cables and/or cable connectors is a problem in any context (not just USB-C, not just USB, not even just electronics).  If you're drawing more power through a cable than it can handle, it will heat up and begin to fail.  At best it will simply fail-open and stop working, but at worst, catch fire, burn your house down and kill your family. :)

Comment: This is misleading. The problem is not in "under-rated" cables. The problem is that some legacy cable assemblies use "false advertising" at Type-C end of LEGACY CABLE ASSEMBLY (using illegal value of CC-pin pull-up), which might cause a Type-C device to draw more power than the classic USB host end can supply. This is entirely a Type-C problem